# what IDE and software can I use to program a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, software, ide

I am aware this sounds like a dumb question, but I'm really unsure what **IDE** / **Software** I could use to programme microcontrollers.

I have a background in **C++**, but I never got to the part where we programmed microcontrollers during my education, so that is why I'm asking here.

As an **IDE**, of course any text editor would do if you know your way around programming languages, but some IntelliSense for **C** would be nice to have. I currently use **VS2013** on a daily basis, but maybe there is some software that can be used as an **IDE** and can be used to compile code and flash on the microcontroller (I have never tried it, but I'm pretty sure **VS** cannot do it).

I have seen many modules that are sold with firmware that requires you to learn their own language (like BGScript for the BLE1xx modules, or the Arduino boards), but I really do not want to learn a new language.

I will try to programme the **nRF51822** microcontroller from **Nordic Semiconductor** and I have read some posts that lead to **IAR Embedded Workbench** which it's pretty expensive for a beginner like me. I've also heard something about **Keil**, yet I'm really not sure what to do since my knowledge of this field is far to low.

I would appreciate some pointers on where to find my answers if this question is to general or to localised or it doesn't make any sense.

**EDIT**: What are your thoughts on [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/features/cpp.html) by **JetBrains**, some guy seemed to have created **C** / **C++** compilers and IntelliSense support for it [here](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=1373) ?

Comment: [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) comes to mind, but I have no experience with it. I personally kinda like good old VI and Makefile.

Comment: Google your Micro of choice and IDE, Mines PIC and I get to https://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en_us/devtools/mplabxc/  a C compiler with their IDE. including C++

Comment: `Makefile`, does that mean I can use Ruby ? Or does this actually refer to something else ?

Comment: What compiler are you going to use? GCC? The nRF51822 SOC has an ARM CORTEX M0 CPU.

Comment: I have no clue which compiler, I'm not limited by that, I can use either a Windows or OSX based machine. On my OSX, I think I've only got the XCode compiler running, on the Win one, there is nothing yet. So I'm starting from ground up, my only limitation would be prices, I do not want to spend $ 1000 for a compiler or new IDE (my budget is limited).

Comment: If you don't want to spend even $1000, I don't think you can afford even Code Sourcery and such like. Eclipse-GCC toolchain (and all the associated headaches), I would think. IAR and Keil are much more expensive.

Comment: I've being there, if you spend time using VS (specially if you used something like Resharper) and you suddenly balance to PIC programming, don't expect their IDEs to be as developed the as the one you've being using, you need to straggle a little bit at first, and us a suggestion i'll go MikroC, i don't remember where i read that but i think you can add the MikroC compiler to VS (but not sure you have to check that)

Comment: You can try Embeetle IDE (https://embeetle.com). It's free and works both on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what you are trying to do. There is not (to my knowledge) a "universal" microcontroller IDE/Programmer out there. You will need to use whatever your chip manufacturer provides.
The IDE's are usually free, or at least there is likely to be a less-featured version offered for free, cause they make money on the repeat hardware sales: the chips themselves, dev boards, programmer/debuggers, etc. Personally, I use Microchip products at my work and their IDE is MPLAB X.
So, pick your hardware first... then check with the manufacturer and get their IDE.

Answer (score 2):

[Microchip](http://www.microchip.com) provides their [MPLAB](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx) IDE for free.  This includes the assemblers, librarian, and linkers needed to create code for any of their microcontrollers.  Microchip has a broad range of PIC and dsPIC microcontrollers, so with a single IDE you can write code from the smallest 8 bit 6-pin PIC 10F to the higher end 16 and 32 bit PICs.

There are also basic version of a C compiler for each micro family available for free, possibly with some limitations on use.  If I remember right, the paid version differs in that higher optimization leves are available.  However, check the web site for details.

Answer (score 1):

Atmel offers a free IDE platform for their AVR micrcontrollers, and from comments on here, other manufacturers also offer free development platforms for their parts.

Comment: Embeetle IDE (https://embeetle.com) is free and supports now also some Arduino boards - or the ATmega328 in general.